# When was Java's "System.out.println()"  overloaded?

Tags: java

Could it still take, for example, an int and print it successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This "Java in a Nutshell" book from 1997 suggests it was like that (= overloaded) back in JDK1.0:

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java/javanut/ch24_52.htm

Comment: Actually, you can just consult the [Java 1.0.2 API docs](http://www.aquaphoenix.com/ref/jdk1.0.2_api/java.io.PrintStream.html#7244) directly.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "yes" - `System.out.println()` has always been overloaded.